# How do I identify the object most 'typical' of a hierarchical clustering analysis?

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, ward

I have used Matlab to carry out hierarchical clustering on habitat types. Each habitat has a set of physical characteristics that are quantifiable. Using a set of 50 habitats with 5 variables per habitat, I ran a hierarchical clustering algorithm using Ward's linkage.

This gave me two clusters:One with 22 habitats and the other with 28.

What I would like to know is: it is possible to identify which one of the 22 habitats in cluster one is the most typical of that cluster (and which one in cluster 2 is the most typical out of the 28).

I thought I could identify the cluster centroid to help me do this, but I don't think that it is possible, since I used Ward's linkage.

Comment: Some contributor may have a more precise approach but a workable heuristic would be to average (or find the mode, depending on scale types) for the habitat characteristics by cluster. This would create "ideal" habitats (really, the centroids) for each. Then, minimize a distance function based on that using, e.g., euclidean distance. The habitat with the smallest squared deviation would be the most representative.

Comment: I would usually want to check a clustering like this with a different way to view the data, principal component analysis if your habitat characteristics are measured. Then I'd plot your clusters on a plot of the first two PCs. Although cluster analysis appeals on various grounds, cluster analyses tend to give little or no guidance on the precise pattern or variability within clusters or indeed on whether clusters are arbitrary subdivisions of a continuum.Ideally the clusters will look distinct on a plot (and make biological sense too!).

Comment: Thanks both. I actually used PCA prior to the hierarchical clustering (I should have mentioned that). @DJohnson your approach worked well for me. I compared the distance between the 5 variables for the mean habitat with every habitat in the cluster using pdist2 in Matlab. This was based on the Euclidean distance..Then the smallest distance identified my typical habitat for the cluster.